# how to fetch calculated ng-model value into an another ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have 3 ng-model, i need to fetch calculated data of the first two into the third one using angularjs

i tried something like this, but doesn'nt work

HTML

```
var urlt = 'http://localhost/tripsheets';
app.factory('tripsheetFactory', function ($http) {
  return {
    getTripsheets: function () {
      return $http.get(urlt + '/all');
    },
    addTripsheet: function (tripsheet) {
      return $http.post(urlt, tripsheet );
    },
    deleteTripsheet: function (tripsheet) {
      return $http.delete(urlt + '?id=' + tripsheet.id);
    },
    updateTripsheet: function (tripsheet) {
      return $http.put(urlt + '?id=' + tripsheet.id, tripsheet);
    }
  };
});

app.controller('TripsheetCtrl', function ($scope, tripsheetFactory) {

  $scope.tripsheets = [];
  $scope.getTotalCalc = function () {
    return $scope.tripsheets.cash*$scope.tripsheets.tax;
  };

  tripsheetFactory.getTripsheets().then(function(data){
    $scope.tripsheets = data.data;
    $scope.tripsheet = {
      tripsheet_num: $scope.tripsheets.length +1,
      cash:null,
      tax:null,
      total: $scope.getTotalCalc()
    };
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already considered, use a watch on the tripsheet object and calculate the value  in the watch

```
$scope.$watch('tripsheets', function(val){
    $scope.tripsheets.total = $scope.tripsheets.cash*$scope.tripsheets.tax;
  }, true);
```

Sample demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/Ml6eLM4vCYz3tPaL8j3n?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You can either set up a watch on the total...

```
$scope.$watch(function() {
    return $scope.tripsheets.cash * $scope.tripsheets.tax;
 }, function(value) {
    $scope.tripsheets.total = value;
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/g8Qm4/)

Or use Object.defineProperty() (requires ES5+)...

```
Object.defineProperty($scope.tripsheets, 'total', {
    get: function(){
        return $scope.tripsheets.cash * $scope.tripsheets.tax;
    }
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ck28F/)